# Snowflake group by errors out on query with information schema

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using information schema to get count of distinct on all columns from schema and table.
I don't have access to create procedures/views/temp_tables. this option is ruled out. All I have access is select

What I wanted to do:
To query information schema for a table get all columns and run count(distinct of each column)

What is my input information schema

What should be my output

```
 table_name column_name no_of_unique elements
```

Approach tried below is the query

```
select 'xyz' as table_name,'{1}', 
count(0) from 
  (select {0} 
   from {1} 
   group by {0} 
   having count(0) > 1 
   from (
     select ARRAY_TO_STRING(array_agg(column_name),',')
     from first_db.information_schema.columns 
     where table_schema='abc' 
     and TABLE_NAME='xyz'));
```

Below is the error I get

```
 SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 8 unexpected '0'. syntax error line 1 at position 17 unexpected '1'. syntax error line 1 at position 30 unexpected '0'. syntax error line 1 at position 53 unexpected 'from'.
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you are trying to do. If you are trying to get the distinct count of a column name within a table then that’s always going to be 1 as a column name is distinct within a table. If you are trying to get the number of distinct values in each column in a table then just query that table. If you want the distinct values in each column but want to dynamically construct the query then you would need a stored procedure to read the information schema, construct the query, execute it and return the results as a table

Comment: I wanted to dynamically calculate distinct column values. I don't have access to create stored procedure

Comment: In which case you’d have to try and write it in a SQL scripting anonymous block

Comment: Can you please help here

Comment: This is probably a good place to start: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/blocks.html. Once you’ve done some research, update your question with what you’ve managed to write on your own and you can ask a specific question on any issue you are facing

Comment: I have seen your snowflake link . As I had mentioned I do not have access to create or replace procedure/functions Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved in two step process

**Step 1:** From information schema I have constructed the process in the format I need
Below is the code

```
select $4 dyn_col,$5 static_col from (
select 'SRC' as db, 'ab_x' as schema_nm,'a' as tbl_nm,ARRAY_TO_STRING(array_agg(concat('count(distinct ',column_name,') ',column_name)),','),ARRAY_TO_STRING(array_agg(column_name),',')
 from edw_src.information_schema.columns where table_schema='ab_x' and 
 TABLE_NAME='a' AND COLUMN_NAME not in ('VALUE'));
```

Above query returns two columns as output . First column will have dynamically constructed columns as count(distinct col1),count(distinct col2)  and second column will have plain "column names separated with commas"

**Step 2:**
Now I put above output results in below query

```
select 'a' as table_name,column_name,column_value no_of_unique_elements from (
select "From above query your count(distinct colums>" from SRC.ab_x.a) 
unpivot(column_value  for column_name in ("column names separated with commas")) 
;
```

Now I get my intended output as expected

```
 table_name column_name no_of_unique_elements
```